# highcharts how to hide legendSymbol in front of particular legend name?

Tags: highcharts

I have four legends say ....
Product1, Product2, Product3, Remove All

now as you guys know every legend have a colour symbol called legendSymbol in front of every legend name.

I want to hide or remove the legendsymbol in front of Remove All legend name only? Also
I want to have more gap between Product3 and Remove All like below
Product1 Product2 Product3         Remove All

Comment: Do you have a JSFiddle example where you can show what you want exactly? It will be much easier with some drawings and code.

Comment: So You would like to remove all legend items, what should be displayed after click ? empty legend?

Answer (score 3):

```
legend: {
        symbolHeight: 0,
        symbolWidth: 0,
        symbolRadius: 0
    }
```

Comment: Since Highcharts 5.0 is seems like you also have to set `squareSymbol: false`.

Answer (score 1):

Use second argument callback function like this

```
$('#container').highcharts( chartObject,(chart)=>{
   chart.series.forEach((serie) = >{
     if (serie.legendSymbol) serie.legendSymbol.destroy();
     if (serie.legendLine) serie.legendLine.destroy();
   })
})
```

Demo https://jsfiddle.net/fahadsaeed/zm763rcq/

Answer (score 0):

One quick easy (imperfect) solution:

http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/JVNjs/295/

```
type:'area',
color:'transparent',
```

One more complicated example that does a variety of things, including placing a button on the chart to hide all series.

http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/57SR9/21/

Answer (score 0):

```
symbolHeight: 0,
symbolWidth: 0,
symbolRadius: 0
```

Set this code inside the legend array

Answer (score 0):

I'm using this to hide the symbols

```
legend: {
  squareSymbol: false,
  symbolHeight: 0,
  symbolWidth: 0,
  symbolRadius: 0
}
```